# How to compute observables from the boson field operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observables

I think I understand that if given the two boson wavefunction of two different states
\begin{align}
\Psi(\boldsymbol{r}_1,\boldsymbol{r}_2)
=
\dfrac{
\psi_1(\boldsymbol{r}_1)\psi_2(\boldsymbol{r}_2)
+
\psi_1(\boldsymbol{r}_2)\psi_2(\boldsymbol{r}_1)
}
{\sqrt{2}}
\end{align}
the expectation value of an operator $\hat{Q}$ for $\Psi(\boldsymbol{r}_1,\boldsymbol{r}_2)$ is 
\begin{align}
\langle \Psi | \hat{Q} | \Psi \rangle
=
\langle \psi_1(\boldsymbol{r}_1) | \hat{Q}_1 | \psi_1(\boldsymbol{r}_1) \rangle
+
\langle \psi_2(\boldsymbol{r}_2) | \hat{Q}_2 | \psi_2(\boldsymbol{r}_2) \rangle
\end{align}
If I add one more boson to state $\psi_1$, then the total wavefunction changes to
\begin{align}
\Psi(\boldsymbol{r}_1,\boldsymbol{r}_2,\boldsymbol{r}_3)
=
\dfrac{
\psi_1(\boldsymbol{r}_1)\psi_1(\boldsymbol{r}_2)\psi_2(\boldsymbol{r}_3)
+
\psi_1(\boldsymbol{r}_2)\psi_1(\boldsymbol{r}_3)\psi_2(\boldsymbol{r}_1)
+
\psi_1(\boldsymbol{r}_3)\psi_1(\boldsymbol{r}_1)\psi_2(\boldsymbol{r}_2)
}
{\sqrt{6}}
\end{align}
The expectation value of $\hat{Q}$ for $\Psi(\boldsymbol{r}_1,\boldsymbol{r}_2,\boldsymbol{r}_3)$ becomes
\begin{align}
\langle \Psi | \hat{Q} | \Psi \rangle
=
2\langle \psi_1(\boldsymbol{r}_1) | \hat{Q}_1 | \psi_1(\boldsymbol{r}_1) \rangle
+
\langle \psi_2(\boldsymbol{r}_2) | \hat{Q}_2 | \psi_2(\boldsymbol{r}_2) \rangle
\end{align}
I am stuck with understanding how to compute the expectation values of $\hat{Q}$ in terms of the boson field operator
\begin{align}
\Psi(\boldsymbol{r})=\sum_{\nu} \psi_{\nu} \left( \boldsymbol{r} \right) b_{\nu}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\left[\Psi(\boldsymbol{r}_1),\Psi^\dagger(\boldsymbol{r}_2)\right]=\delta (\boldsymbol{r}_1-\boldsymbol{r}_2) 
\\
[b_\alpha^\dagger,b_\beta^\dagger]=[b_\alpha,b_\beta]=0,\quad [b_\alpha,b_\beta^\dagger]=\delta_{\alpha\beta}
\end{align}
I am assuming that 
\begin{align}
\langle 
\psi_{\mu}^\dagger \left( \boldsymbol{r} \right)
|
\psi_{\nu} \left( \boldsymbol{r} \right)
\rangle
=
\int
\psi_{\mu}^\dagger \left( \boldsymbol{r} \right)
\psi_{\nu} \left( \boldsymbol{r} \right)
d^3\boldsymbol{r}
=
\delta_{\mu\nu}
\end{align}

Comment: Could you clarify what's giving you trouble? The computation of expectation values in multi-particle states is no different from computing them from single particle states

Comment: @ACuriousMind I am going to edit the question to be specific to a particle field.

Comment: I'm afraid I still have no idea what your question might be. Is $\Psi$ a wavefunction or is it an operator (you say the former, but the $b_\nu$ seem to indicate it is the latter)? What do you want to compute and where is your problem in doing so?

Comment: I am still trying to add more detail to the question. I  $\boldsymbol{\Psi}$ is an operator I believe.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I made some edits to the question. I will transfer the post to a new post, because I was told that on hold questions can never be redeemed.

Comment: They can! Don't post this anew, it will only be closed as duplicate. Since you edited it, it is automatically placed in the reopen queue, and will be reopened if it is clear. *But* you seem to be conflating QFT and QM objects here, and the question still makes little sense to me. The boson field $\Psi(\vec r)$ is a QFT object, it is an operator distribution, while your wavefunctions are simply functions taking values in $\mathbb{C}$. They are not at all the same, and the boson field does not represent a state, so you cannot calculate any expectation value from it.

Comment: @linuxfreebird: Who told you that on-hold questions can never be redeemed?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I think that is my confusion. I am confusing that the field operator is a different representation of the total wavefunction. I need help in unconfusing my confusion. I do not know how to make sense of the two completely different objects. I keeping confusing the idea that they are some related , but I do not know how. I need some serious help. The quantization of the electromagnetic field makes it even worse for me, in separating the two ideas.

Comment: The field operator has nothing to do with the wavefunction, it is a quantum field theory concept, while the wavefunction is a QM concept (which *can* appear in QFT generalized to a wavefunction*al*, but need not). You should stick to QM and when you have understood that to your satisfaction, you can move on to fields. For now, I would advise to steer clear of anything that talks about "fields" - or to grab a QFT book/course and learn it properly.

Comment: @ACuriousMind what about reopen the question and clarify the confusion in an answer? The OP being confused about something is not a legitimate (keep) close(d) reason...

Comment: @Dilaton: Correct, but what's the question here? I'll gladly vote for reopen if it is changed to something like "What's the difference between a many-particle wavefunction and a quantum field?", but since that's a rather radical change, I'll not edit that in myself. The question *as it currently reads* is precisely what is stated in the close reason: unclear.

Comment: @ACuriousMind well the question is what it currently says, and the clarification of the difference between the wave function and a quantum field should be part of an answer, because this is the conceptual roadblock that prevents him to do the calculation. IMHO it can therefore be reopend as is.

Comment: I found this pdf and I am currently reading it. I think it provides some insight into the problem for me at least. https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ifi.unicamp.br%2Fgpoms%2Fcurso%2520gaston%25202010%2Frobertson.pdf&ei=hMjRU5P1Dq7MsQTmh4GoAQ&usg=AFQjCNExYYb21Yur9x9EBbwiswU7hJPMJg&sig2=5A_p0J1gjhDp3RnlsStoaQ&bvm=bv.71667212,d.cWc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In quantum field theory, you change the space of wavefunctions w.r.t. quantum mechanics. The space is still a Hilbert space, but it is called Fock space, and it takes into account the possibility of having any number of identical "particles" (or excitations of the field). A vector of such Fock space is of this form:
$$(\psi_0,\psi_1,\psi_2,\psi_3,\dotsc)$$
where $\psi_1$ is an usual QM wavefunction of one particle, $\psi_2$ is the symmetric (for bosons) completion of products $\psi(x_1)\phi(x_2)$ of single-particle wavefunctions etc... $\psi_0$ is the state with no particles, or vacuum. Mathematically, the Fock space have a particularly nice structure described by means of direct sums and (symmetric) tensor products of Hilbert spaces. Let $\mathscr{H}$ be the one particle Hilbert space, then the symmetric Fock space $\Gamma_s(\mathscr{H})$ is
$$\Gamma_s(\mathscr{H})=\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty \mathscr{H}_n\; ,\; \mathscr{H}_n=\underbrace{\mathscr{H}\otimes_s\dotsc\otimes_s\mathscr{H}}_{n}$$
with the convention $\mathscr{H}_0=\mathbb{C}$.

So the $\Psi$ you have written above is some ***state*** belonging to one of the $\mathscr{H}_n$, not an operator by any means. Then you write the observable $Q$ as acting like a one particle operator on each particle. This type of operator is possible in the Fock space and it is called second quantization of $Q$. However it is not the only possible operator. Given $Q$ acting on $\mathscr{H}\equiv\mathscr{H}_1$, the second quantization $d\Gamma(Q)$ acts on $\mathscr{H}_n$ as
$$Q\otimes1\otimes\dotsc\otimes1 +1\otimes Q\otimes1\otimes\dotsc\otimes1+\dotsc+1\otimes\dotsc\otimes Q\; ;$$
and on $\mathscr{H}_0$ as zero ($1$ is the identity operator on $\mathscr{H}$). So computing the average of a second quantization $\langle\Psi,d\Gamma(Q)\Psi\rangle$  (where $\Psi\in\Gamma_s(\mathscr{H})$) may be quite easy.

But there are other types of operators on the Fock space as you can imagine, in particulare those who relate $\mathscr{H}_n$ with $\mathscr{H}_{n+1}$ and vice versa. The most famous ones of this type are the creation and annihilation operators $a^*(x)$ and $a(x)$ ($[a(x),a^*(y)]=\delta(x-y)$), and are the fundamental operators of the Fock space, as momentum and position are of the QM space. The boson field, in its simplest form, is just a combination of the two: let $f\in\mathscr{H}$, then the field $\phi(f)$ is
$$\phi(f)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(a^*(f)+a(f))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int \bigl(a^*(x)f(x)+a(x)\bar{f}(x)\bigr)dx\; .$$
As you see this operator relates $\mathscr{H}_n$ with $\mathscr{H}_{n+1}$ and $\mathscr{H}_{n-1}$ and it is self-adjoint, so you can think of it as another type of observable (and not a state!) on the Fock space. Also of it you can compute $\langle \Psi, \phi(f)\Psi\rangle$ but it is not an easy calculation as before...You can also see how the field interacts with the second quantization of $Q$, but by means e.g. of calculating their commutator $[\phi(f),d\Gamma(Q)]$. Hope this helps to clarify a little bit ;-)